# Is it true that women's style of play tend on average to be slightly more aggressive than men's style of play?

Tags: strategy, positional-play, aggressive-play

> As we know, women chess is much more unpredictable than men’s. Women chess is also uncompromised and very entertaining. Men chess is more solid, pragmatic and conservative, and women game, on the contrary, is brighter, more emotional.
>
> -Andrei Selivanov, Vice-President of the Russian Chess Federation

Is this true? Do women tend on average to be more aggressive and more tactical in nature while men are more solid and positional?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The evidence I've heard for the argument you saw was that top women's play has a lower draw rate than top men's play. The problem with that line of thinking is that if you look at men's games at the same Elo level as the top women, about 2500-2600, the draw rate is the same.

Comment: Another reason for this over-generalization is the presence of Judit Polgár, the undisputed best female player in history, who happens to have a very aggressive play style.